# NSIS compiler and parameters

Tags: batch-file, installation, nsis

How can I set some variables in my nsis script in compile time?
for example:

```
makensis.exe myscript.nsi "buildversion"
```

I want to set buildversion in my script during compile time.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
makensis -Dbuildversion=1.2.3.4 myscript.nsi
```

-D sets a !define, not a variable ( `${adefine}`, `$avariable` ) and you have to get the order of -D and the script correct...